# Seqelize N:M with Join table update

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

Currently I have a join table user_roles, user model and the role model, I want to update the role of a particular user after it's initially set.

user_roles - Join table between user and role

```
<code>db.user = require("../models/user.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.role = require("../models/role.model.js")(sequelize, Sequelize);

db.role.belongsToMany(db.user, {
    through: "user_roles",
    foreignKey: "roleId",
    otherKey: "userId"
});
db.user.belongsToMany(db.role, {
    through: "user_roles",
    foreignKey: "userId",
    otherKey: "roleId"
});</code>
```

User model

```
<code>
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("users", {
        username: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        email: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        password: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING
        },
        resetPasswordToken: Sequelize.STRING,
        resetPasswordExpires: Sequelize.STRING,
    }); 
    return User; }; </code>
```

Role Model

```
<code>module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
  const Role = sequelize.define("roles", {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
    }
  });

  return Role;
};</code>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'update the role of a particular user' ? You mean a record in user_roles?

Comment: Make a put on user_roles, update the role(change the role, example: from user to admin).
The roleId refers to the roels that the users have
The userId refers to the individual Id they they have

Example:
The user_roles has
roleId 1
userId 1

roleId 1 refers to a role that is in the role table( 1 admin, 2 user)
userId 1 refers to the user that is in the user table(username, email, password)
I want for example to update the id 1 of userId to roleId 2, so the role changes from admin to user

Comment: user.setRole(2) is what you wish to get?

Comment: No, you can't set that due to the fact that role property is not in the user model.

I need to update user_role table since the role property is there

Comment: SOLVED! Anatoly helped! Thanks a lot.

I created a route api/auth/updateRole which requires two methods, check if the user is admin and validates the token.

This route calls for controller which updates the role, first it finds the user and updates the role

Comment: user.setRole(2) in case of belongToMany writes in user_roles table

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I highly appreciate  your help

Comment: @Anatoly, I know this is old post, but it would be great if you could write an answer for this post with short elaboration on how sequelize works with N:M relations and maybe a few links. You will have my upvote and, I am sure, many more from thankful users in years to come.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have M:N relationship here and use `belongsToMany` then you can call `setRole` method of the `User` model instance to replace roles linked to a certain user by passing role ids there:

```js
await user.setRoles([2])
```

To add new user roles to existing ones you can use `addRole`/`addRoles`.
Please look at the official documentation [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html#special-methods-mixins-added-to-instances) to see what special methods Sequelize adds to model instances dynamically in case of different types of associations.